# Statement vs expression vs assignment in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, terminology

I understand that a variable declaration is a statement (and not an expression, as it cannot be evaluated)

```
let a
```

I understand that an assignment is also a statement and an expression, as it can be evaluated in JS)

```
a= 2
```

I also understand that when I declare and assign a value in the same line, this is considered a statement and not an expression, as it cannot be evaluated:

```
let a = 5
```

My question is:

**If these 2 things (declaration + assignment) are happening in the same line, why is it considered a declaration?**

An expression is expected as an argument here:

```
console.log(let a=3)
> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

but an assignment is an expression as it can indeed be passed as an argument:

```
console.log(a=3)
3
```

Comment: "*If these 2 things (declaration + assignment) are happening in the same line, why is it considered a declaration?*" because it's *not* an assignment. It's actually still part of the declaration syntax - where you can optionally initialise a variable.